# "Starter Motor Solenoid relay Switch"

Tags: electrical, ford, starter, f-250

2002 Ford F250 5.4L Manual claims there is a "Starter Motor Solenoid relay Switch" (part #11450). Picture does not show location. Anybody know where it is?
I seem to think the manual is incorrect! Solenoid also attached to starter.
Would appreciate any feedback.

Comment: Is this a pickup or a cab and chassis? It should be under the driver side dash in the fuse box.

Comment: Note that there is the solenoid which is located on the starter motor, and also a solenoid relay which will typically be on a relay or distribution panel (which could be colocated with the fuse panel). The relay's job is to switch power to the solenoid, which is responsible for pulling in the starter motor and switching it on.

Comment: what manual? ..

Answer (score 1):

The 11450 is the standard Ford solenoid which is used to energize the starter motor. It takes place of the one on the starter itself which you'll see on many other vehicles. It should be mounted on the passenger's side fender well inside the engine compartment. The positive lead from the battery (the thick one) should lead directly to it. The solenoid looks likes this:

[image]